# Outlier count mismatch between boxplot and IQR

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, outliers

I have a single df containing the numbers where i'm trying to identify the outliers.

trtbps = [145
130
130
120
120
140
140
120
172
150
140
130
130
110
150
120
120
150
150
140
135
130
140
150
140
160
150
110
140
130
105
120
130
125
125
142
135
150
155
160
140
130
104
130
140
120
140
138
128
138
130
120
130
108
135
134
122
115
118
128
110
108
118
135
140
138
100
130
120
124
120
94
130
140
122
135
125
140
128
105
112
128
102
152
102
115
118
101
110
100
124
132
138
132
112
142
140
108
130
130
148
178
140
120
129
120
160
138
120
110
180
150
140
110
130
120
130
120
105
138
130
138
112
108
94
118
112
152
136
120
160
134
120
110
126
130
120
128
110
128
120
115
120
106
140
156
118
150
120
130
160
112
170
146
138
130
130
122
125
130
120
132
120
138
138
160
120
140
130
140
130
110
120
132
130
110
117
140
120
150
132
150
130
112
150
112
130
124
140
110
130
128
120
145
140
170
150
125
120
110
110
125
150
180
160
128
110
150
120
140
128
120
118
145
125
132
130
130
135
130
150
140
138
200
110
145
120
120
170
125
108
165
160
120
130
140
125
140
125
126
160
174
145
152
132
124
134
160
192
140
140
132
138
100
160
142
128
144
150
120
178
112
123
108
110
112
180
118
122
130
120
134
120
100
110
125
146
124
136
138
136
128
126
152
140
140
134
154
110
128
148
114
170
152
120
140
124
164
140
110
144
130
130]

Using the boxplot I'm able to identify 6 outliers as shown below

[image: Boxplot]

However, when i manually try to calculate the outliers using IQR, I'm getting 9 different outliers as shown using below.

```
#Calculating the IQR
IQR = df.trtbps.quantile(0.75) - df.trtbps.quantile(0.25)

#Calculating the upper and lower boundaries 

lower_bridge=df['trtbps'].quantile(0.25)-(IQR*1.5)
upper_bridge=df['trtbps'].quantile(0.75)+(IQR*1.5)
print(lower_bridge), print(upper_bridge)

#Printing the outliers in trtbps column based on upper and lower boundaries
print(df[(df['trtbps'] > upper_bridge) | (df['trtbps'] < lower_bridge)])
```

Output :

```
         trtbps  
8         172   
101       178   
110       180   
203       180  
223       200   
241       174   
248       192   
260       178   
266       180
```

Question is why the count of outliers mismatching between boxplot and manually calculated outliers ? Shouldn't the count be the same between both of them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outliers *are* the same. You just cannot count them in the boxplot, because three of them have the value 180, and two have the value 178. These two groups will appear as one point each in the plot. This accounts for the three "missing" points.